# How to authorise user in fabric chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In my chaincode I want only a specific user to be able to do a particular action. This user will be selected at the time of initialisation.

Just like in ethereum we can check the sender address and decide to let the user do a particular thing or not. What is similar to this in hyperledger?

What is the unique identifier of a user in hyperledger? I am using fabric 1.0.

Kindly provide a simple code example also.

Answer (score 0):

You can send info needed to authorization in the transient field of the proposal , and you can get it using GetTransient() function. Or the GetCreator() function.

Comment: I don't want to send any info explicitly. Otherwise anyone can send this info and authorise. I want to use the transaction to find the member.